# getting a syntax error when parsing assignment statement in yacc

Tags: c, yacc, lex

[Caution Homework]

I need a hint as to why the following code is failing when I try to run the test case: `int a = 3;` All the code compiles with no warnings or errors, and as far as I can tell the structure is correct.I feel there must be a problem in the rules for `assignment`.

The error message says: `ERROR: syntax error at symbol "a" on line 1`

This is the .lex file:

```
%{

#include "calc.h"
#include "symbol-table.h"
#include "tok.h"
int yyerror(char *s);
int yylinenum = 1;
%}

digit        [0-9]
int_const    {digit}+
float_const  {digit}+[.]{digit}+
id           [a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*

%%

{int_const}    { yylval.int_val = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER_LITERAL; }
{float_const}  { yylval.float_val = atof(yytext); return FLOAT_LITERAL; }
"="            { yylval.str_val = strdupclean(yylval.str_val, yytext); return EQUALS; }
"+"            { yylval.str_val = strdupclean(yylval.str_val, yytext); return PLUS; }
"*"            { yylval.str_val = strdupclean(yylval.str_val, yytext); return MULT; }
"-"            { yylval.str_val = strdupclean(yylval.str_val, yytext); return MINUS; }
"/"            { yylval.str_val = strdupclean(yylval.str_val, yytext); return DIV; }
"("            { yylval.str_val = strdupclean(yylval.str_val, yytext); return OPAREN; }
")"            { yylval.str_val = strdupclean(yylval.str_val, yytext); return CPAREN; }
";"            { yylval.str_val = strdupclean(yylval.str_val, yytext); return SEMIC; }
"sqrt"         { yylval.str_val = strdupclean(yylval.str_val, yytext); return SQRT; }
{id}           { yylval.str_val = strdupclean(yylval.str_val, yytext); 
                 /*HINT: One way to simplify parsing is to have lex return what
                  * type of variable we have.  IVAR = int, FVAR = float
                  * UVAR = unknown var.
                  * Naturally, you may use your own solution.
                  */
              if (strcmp(yylval.str_val, "int")) {return IVAR;}
              else if (strcmp(yylval.str_val, "float")) {return FVAR;}
                  else {return UVAR;} 
               }

[ \t]*         {}
[\n]           { yylinenum++;    }

.              { yyerror("Unknown Symbol"); exit(1); }
%%
```

and this is the yacc file:

```
%{
#include "calc.h"
#include "symbol-table.h"
int yyerror(char *s);
int yylex(void);
%}

%union{
int         int_val;
float       float_val;
char*       str_val;
}

%start input

%token <int_val>   INTEGER_LITERAL
%token <float_val> FLOAT_LITERAL
%token <float_val> SQRT
%token OPAREN CPAREN SEMIC IVAR FVAR UVAR
%type  <int_val>   int_exp
%type  <float_val> float_exp
%type  <str_val>  IVAR FVAR UVAR
%right EQUALS /*right associative, everything on the right side of the = should be evaluated and stored*/
%left  PLUS MINUS/*The order matters, by listing PLUS/MIUS first and then MULT/DIV we are */
%left  MULT DIV /*telling yacc to evaluate MULTs & DIVs before PLUSes and MINUSes*/

%%

input:           /*empty*/
            | int_exp                   { printf("Result %d\n", $1); }
            | float_exp                 { printf("Result %f\n", $1); }
            | assignment                { printf("Result \n"); }
            ;

int_exp:          INTEGER_LITERAL           { $$ = $1; }
            | int_exp PLUS int_exp      { $$ = $1 + $3; }
            | int_exp MULT int_exp      { $$ = $1 * $3; }
            | int_exp MINUS int_exp     { $$ = $1 - $3; }
            | int_exp DIV int_exp       { $$ = $1 / $3; }
            | OPAREN int_exp CPAREN     { $$ = $2; }
            ;

float_exp:        FLOAT_LITERAL             { $$ = $1; }
            | float_exp PLUS float_exp  { $$ = $1 + $3; }
            | float_exp MULT float_exp  { $$ = $1 * $3; }
            | float_exp MINUS float_exp { $$ = $1 - $3; }
            | float_exp DIV float_exp   { $$ = $1 / $3; }
            | int_exp PLUS float_exp    { $$ = (float)$1 + $3; }
            | int_exp MULT float_exp    { $$ = (float)$1 * $3; }
            | int_exp MINUS float_exp   { $$ = (float)$1 - $3; }
            | int_exp DIV float_exp     { $$ = (float)$1 / $3; }
            | float_exp PLUS int_exp    { $$ = (float)$1 + $3; }
            | float_exp MULT int_exp    { $$ = (float)$1 * $3; }
            | float_exp MINUS int_exp   { $$ = (float)$1 - $3; }
            | float_exp DIV int_exp     { $$ = (float)$1 / $3; }
            | OPAREN float_exp CPAREN   { $$ = $2; }
            | SQRT OPAREN float_exp CPAREN  { $$ = sqrt((double)$3); }
            | SQRT OPAREN int_exp CPAREN    { $$ = sqrt((double)$3); }
            ;

assignment:       UVAR EQUALS float_exp SEMIC           { //if UVAR exists and is float, update value
                                          //if UVAR doesn't exist, error: unknown type
                                          symbol_table_node *n1 = symbol_table_find( $1, *st);
                                          if(n1) { 
                                            if(n1->type == FLOAT_TYPE) {
                                                n1->val.float_val = $3;
                                            } else {
                                                //error
                                            }
                                            //error, variable not defined
                                          //if UVAR is not float, error: illegal assignment
                                          }
                                        }
            | UVAR EQUALS int_exp SEMIC         { 
                                          symbol_table_node *n1 = symbol_table_find( $1, *st);
                                          if(n1) { 
                                            if(n1->type == INT_TYPE) {
                                                n1->val.int_val = $3;
                                            } else {
                                                //error
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
            | IVAR UVAR EQUALS int_exp SEMIC { //UVAR should not be in symbol table
                                          if(symbol_table_find($2, *st)) {
                                            //error
                                          } else {
                                            //how to handle errors?
                                            symbol_table_add_i($2, $4, *st);
                                          }
                                        }
            | FVAR UVAR EQUALS float_exp SEMIC { 
                                          if(symbol_table_find($2, *st)) {

                                          } else {
                                            symbol_table_add_f($2, $4, *st);
                                          }
                                        }
            ;

%%

int yyerror(char *s){
extern int yylinenum; /* defined and maintained in lex.c*/
extern char *yytext;  /* defined and maintained in lex.c*/

printf("ERROR: %s at symbol \"%s\" on line %d\n", s, yytext, yylinenum);
return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is simple enough:

```
if (strcmp(yylval.str_val, "int"))
```

does not do what you think it does. `strcmp` returns `0` if the two strings are equal, a negative value if the first one is lexicographically earlier, and a positive value if the first one is lexicographically later. Used as a boolean, that means that `strcmp` is `false` if the string compare equal, and `true` otherwise. So the token `int` will not generate the token value `IVAL`.

But I don't think that's really what you wanted to do, anyway. Your instructor's hint about having the lexer return a token type corresponding to the known datatype of the token is referring to looking the variable up in the symbol table and returning a token type corresponding to the declaration of the variable. It's not referring to recognizing the reserved words `int` and `float`, which should be done with simple lexer rules, much like your rule for the reserved word `sqrt`.

As written, your grammar does not allow expressions to use variables, so (even after you fix the bug I referred to), the following will fail:

```
int b = 0;
int a = b + 3;
```

because `b` won't be recognized as an `int_exp`. It's in this context that the instructor's hint applies. (Although personally, I would suggest doing it differently.)

Finally, I don't know what `strdupclean` does, but I presume it involves making a copy of `yytext`. That's almost certainly unnecessary in the case of operator tokens (`+`, `-`, and so on) or reserved words, since you will never refer to the "semantic value" of those tokens. (As evidence, you don't declare any of these tokens to even have a semantic type.) Unnecessary copying does have a cost, particularly if you need to clean up the memory allocated for the copy.

Good luck.